# windows phone 7.. play or pause the music

Tags: windows-phone-7

i am developing game in windows phone 7. i want to add a button on homepage which  allow to toggle between images.

i wrote following code but doesnt work

int key = 1;

```
        switch (key)
        { 
            case 1:
                 var brush = new ImageBrush();
            BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"Assets/small/misc/music pause button.png", UriKind.Relative));
            brush.ImageSource = image;
            music.Background = brush;
            key=0;

                break;

            case 0:
                 var brush2 = new ImageBrush();
            BitmapImage image2 = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"Assets/small/misc/music pause button.png", UriKind.Relative));
            brush2.ImageSource = image2;
            music.Background = brush2;
            key = 1;

                break;

        }
```

Comment: Is it normal that in both case you are using the same image (music pause button.png)? Also otherwise you should decribe what "doesnt work", (do it crash? the image don't change? the image don't show up?, something else...)

Comment: thnx its solved...actually i placed key=1 in the loop...so every time it was 1 not changing to 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved this by using togglebutton

in xaml there is toggle button control
   `<ToggleButton Name="tog" Margin="555,358,0,7" IsChecked="{x:Null}" Checked="tog_Checked" Unchecked="tog_Unchecked" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" BorderThickness="0" IsThreeState="False" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="123"></ToggleButton>`

now add code on event handlers :

```
    private void tog_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        tog.Background = brush;
        togkey = 1;
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("1");
    }

    private void tog_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        tog.Background = null;
        togkey = 0;
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("0");
    }
```